# want to capture data after the search action using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am working on a ERP application, where I have to click on a search button, after which it will give me list of data.

Want automate that using webdriver

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcCr7.gif)
[image]

The search tab is empty before the search option.

How to check, whether the data is coming after pressing the search button or not?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have not tried anything so far as I don't have idea how to capture that. suppose for a example if I am in myntra.com and in the search bar I have written jeans and hit the Search button. How will I know whether website is giving any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the data in a tabular form you can use something like:

```
List<WebElements> tableRows = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
```

and then you can check the size and do whatever you want.

Comment: hi, I tried but I am not able to figure out . 
Lets take this page 
http://www.kluniversity.in/Programmes.aspx
Could you help me in picking the data from the table

Comment: you can use below code for this page.


WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.kluniversity.in/Programmes.aspx");
  WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("box-table-a"));
  List<WebElement> tableRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
  System.out.println("Number of rows :"+tableRows.size());
  // To print all the elements of a table
  for(WebElement row:tableRows){
    List<WebElement> tableCols=row.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
    for(WebElement cols:tableCols){
     System.out.print(cols.getText()+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

Comment: Thanks. its working now....
I referred selenium docs for some info but its not complete. Could you recommend some books or website for me to refer?